# On what basis can we decide a particular Java application is a Java EE application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am working on a Java application which uses Servlets, an application server, JMS, JMX etc.

So is this a Java EE application? And are there any particular criteria to say a particular application is a Java EE application?

Comment: why do you need such criteria? You want to put on your CV "I've been doing JEE" ? If yes - don't bother, it won't have any effect - just list the major APIs you've used

Comment: I don't think the question should receive minuses. It is common misunderstanding. And I saw a lot of books which were named J2EE and inside there was Hibernate (which not it the EE list).

Comment: The short answer is that if you're using an application server (jboss, weblogic, glassfish, etc.) then you're running j2ee

Comment: @kevindtimm, not obligitary, you can use just spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't completely agree with the other answers.

You have a Java EE application if you can **package** it as a `.war` or an `.ear` and **deploy** it according to the Java EE standards.

If you have a stand-alone application which uses JMS, it doesn't make it a Java EE application in the sense most people will understand it. Same for JMX, JavaMail or other APIs. Still, such an application would use the Java EE API. But in your case, I would say, yes, you have a Java EE application.

Comment: By packaging application as WAR or EAR did not make it JAVA EE application because it can contain a single html page or entertain one user. This did not fulfill enterprise application criteria.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is called Java EE now
2. [Here's a list](http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/javaee5.jsp) of Java EE technologies. If you are using any of them, your application is Java EE.

But it doesn't matter how you are going to call it.
Would it matter if you are going to call your application an "apache commons application" in case you are using any of the apache commons libraries? No :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it is pretty simple. If you application uses the Java EE API which *is provided to you* by some Application Server then your application is a Java EE application.

List of EE APIs:

http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/javaee5.jsp

Comment: Why not, if JEE is provided to you by application server.

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are part of Java EE.

If you look for javax.servlet you'll find it in the javaee jar. Some of the technologies in Java EE (from http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/) are:

- Servlets
- Web Services
- Enterprise Java Beans
- Java Persistence
- Java Message Services
- Java Transactions
- Java API for XML Processing
- Java Mail
- Java Authentication

Answer (score 0):

If your application is using any Java EE API, then you can consider your application based on Java EE technology.

You can check the docs for the Java EE APIs.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using any of these `Java EE specification` and fulfilling `Enterprise application` software criteria, then your application is EE.**

**First you need to know what is enterprise software/application.**

Enterprise application software is application software that performs business functions such as order processing, procurement, production scheduling, customer information management, energy management, and accounting. It is typically hosted on servers and provides simultaneous services to a large number of users, typically over a computer network. This is in contrast to a single-user application that is executed on a user's personal computer and serves only one user at a time.

**Java EE has many specifications:** 
such as JDBC, RMI, e-mail, JMS, web services, XML, etc., and defines how to coordinate them. Java EE also features some specifications unique to Java EE for components. These include Enterprise JavaBeans, Connectors, servlets, JavaServer Pages and several web service technologies. This allows developers to create enterprise applications that are portable and scalable, and that integrate with legacy technologies.