# When an application can be considered as a Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [on what basis we can decide a particular java appliaction as a J2EE application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092435/on-what-basis-we-can-decide-a-particular-java-appliaction-as-a-j2ee-application)

I am new in Java EE and i am not understanding a when an application can be considered as a Java EE application. For example, i have used jsp and servelet for a website is that a Java EE application, may be not. It seems to me that by using some specific technology, API, framework, library an application can be considered as a Java EE application. If i am right then what is that. How i can define an application either a Java EE application or not. I am really confusing about this. Help me if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Please read [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee), Java EE specifications are defined by JCP. An JavaEE application is one which is built using JavaEE technology.

**For more read**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_application

http://jcp.org/en/home/index

Answer (score 1):

**First you need to know what is enterprise software/application.**

Enterprise application software is application software that performs business functions such as order processing, procurement, production scheduling, customer information management, energy management, and accounting. It is typically hosted on servers and provides simultaneous services to a large number of users, typically over a computer network. This is in contrast to a single-user application that is executed on a user's personal computer and serves only one user at a time.

**Java EE has many specifications:**
such as JDBC, RMI, e-mail, JMS, web services, XML, etc., and defines how to coordinate them. Java EE also features some specifications unique to Java EE for components. These include Enterprise JavaBeans, Connectors, servlets, JavaServer Pages and several web service technologies. This allows developers to create enterprise applications that are portable and scalable, and that integrate with legacy technologies.

**If you are using any of these `Java EE specification` and fulfilling `Enterprise application` software criteria, then your application is EE.**

Answer (score 0):

You could take an overview on what is specified on Java EE 6 API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/). In the documentation you will find specification for:

- **JPA** - Java Persistence API;
- **JTA** - Java Transaction API;
- **Servlets**;
- **CDI** - Dependence Injection;
- **EJB** - Enterprise Java Beans;
- **JSF** - Java Server Faces;
- **JACC** - Java Authorization Contract for Containers;
- **JSP** - Java Server Pages

and others.